# how do I recover my previous google account?

Tags: google-account, account-recovery

Out of desparation I opened a new google account an hour ago because I was getting nowhere trying to recover my old one which worked fine yesterday

Answer (score 0):

You go to https://google.com and then click `Sign In`, next click `Forgot Password` and then follow all the steps it tells you.

Comment: I've tried this several times and they keep telling me to check back in 3 hours.  I couldn't remember my password and tried several different ones and I think they decided I was a bad person because now I can't go any further in the system.  It's has just cut me off apparently.  I don't know what to do.